# If $\hat{a}+\hat{b}+\hat{c}=0$, and $x,y,z$ distinct are integers, find the possible values of $|x\hat{a}+y\hat{b}+z\hat{c}|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

If $\hat{a}+\hat{b}+\hat{c}=0$, and $x,y,z$ are distinct integers, which of the values are not possible for $|x\hat{a}+y\hat{b}+z\hat{c}|$? ($a,b,c$ are unit vectors)

1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. $\sqrt{2}$

Let $R=x\hat{a}+y\hat{b}+z\hat{c}$
$$R\cdot R=|R|^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy(\hat{a}\cdot\hat{b})+ 2yz(\hat{b}\cdot\hat{c}) +2xz(\hat{a}\cdot\hat{c})$$

Edit:

I found out that the angle between the vectors are $120^{\circ}$.

$$|R|^2=\frac{1}{2}[(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2]$$

Its minimum value is $\frac{6}{2}=3$.

Hence $|R|\ge \sqrt{3}$

Comment: If $\hat{a}+\hat{b}+\hat{c}=0$, what can you tell about the angle between them?

Comment: I.e.; they must form equilateral triangle.